# Where should my Man script be located for it to work?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, manpage

I'm trying to create a man script with out any success. Where in my files should I be placing my testScript.1 file for it to work visually as a man page?

So far I've tried by storing it just within two newly created directories in my home directory like so:

```
~/lab2/man1/testScript.1
```

I've also tried compressing the testScript.1 file into a tar.xz file and manually moving it to **/usr/share/man/man1** with the file manager, but permission seems to be denied for some reason.

Also, when I try:

```
man testscript
```

the only result is: **"No manual entry for testscript"**

Where should it be located and how do I get it in there when **"permission is denied"** Thanks

Comment: [What is `MANPATH`](https://www.google.com/search?q=what+is+MANPATH) for the win!

Comment: man will also search the path and for specific directories off of it--unless and administrator has set up something different.  In this case, if `~/lab2/bin` was on the path, then `~/lab2/share/man/man1/testScript.1` should work too.  Of course, you can just specify the path on the man command line too: `man ~/lab2/man1/testScript.1`.  And yes, areas like `/usr/share` are owned by root, so you'd need special permission to put the file there.

Comment: Finally, something worked! I tried: **man ~/lab2/man1/testScript.1**
and that worked! How would I go about just shorting that to **man**? @JohnSzakmeister

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either put your manual pages in the shared location (and you need root privileges for that) or store them wherever you want and tell `man` to use that folder.

From `man` man page:

```
   -M  path
          Specify the list of directories to search for man pages.  Separate the directories with colons.  An empty list is the same as not specifying -M at all.  See SEARCH PATH FOR MANUAL PAGES.
```

Answer (score 0):

On my system, I simply launched `man man`, giving (amonst others) following results:

```
ENVIRONMENT
   MANPATH
          If $MANPATH is set, its value is used as the path to search for manual pages.
   ...

FILES
   /etc/manpath.config
          man-db configuration file.

   /usr/share/man
          A global manual page hierarchy.

   /usr/share/man/index.(bt|db|dir|pag)
          A traditional global index database cache.

   /var/cache/man/index.(bt|db|dir|pag)
```

While checking the `/etc/manpath.config`, I've seen this:

```
# There are three mappings allowed in this file:
# --------------------------------------------------------
# MANDATORY_MANPATH                     manpath_element
# MANPATH_MAP           path_element    manpath_element
# MANDB_MAP             global_manpath  [relative_catpath]
#---------------------------------------------------------
...
```

Apparently there's a link between the location of your script and the place where to look for the `man`-pages.

I could explain how it's done, but as I expect this to be different on every system, I'd advise you to launch the mentioned commands and read the config file, it's quite self-explaining.